# Time needed for light beam to reach a moving object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, speed-of-light

[image]

I came across this question, and apparently the correct answer is $1.5$ seconds. However, if the spaceship is moving toward the planet, the distance needed to be covered by the light before it reaches the spaceship decreases? Shouldn't the answer be $1$ second, since the light will travel $3 \times 10^8$ metres, and the spaceship will travel $1.5 \times 10^8$ metres, which adds up to $4.5 \times 10^8$ metres.

Comment: Is the speed of the spaceship measured by someone on the planet? Or is it the speed of the planet as measured by the spaceship? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is indeed 1.5 s.

My reasoning goes the following way:
We place ourselves in the rest frame of the spaceship. So, from our perspective, from our reference frame, the planet is coming towards us. Suddenly, when the planet is at a distance $L$ (as measured by someone who's inside the spaceship) from us, a pulse of light is emitted from this planet. Please note that it's very important to know if $L$ is the distance measured from the spaceship or from the Earth. In this case there is no issue, because, as the text says, $L$ is measured from the spaceship.

Now that your light pulse is emitted you can as well forget about the planet. We don't care what the planet is doing anymore, as we are interested in the pulse of light.

So, we are simply at rest, and the light has to travel the length $L$ to reach us. Remember that the speed of light is the same in every reference frame, thus it's always $c$. I think that this is the concept that this problem wants to enlighten.

So we simply have to do:
\begin{equation}
t=\frac{L}{c}=\frac{4.5}{3}=1.5 \text{ s}
\end{equation}

Comment: Oh right, I get what you're saying, but how would one get to this answer if we didn't look at it from the rest frame of the spaceship? Or is that mandatory for questions like this?

Comment: It's not mandatory, but the text wants to know "how much does it take according to people on the spaceship?", so it's the smarter way. From a different reference frame you would have get another answer, because of "time dilation", and then you'd have had to "transform" your result to the spaceship rf. You see, in relativity "time"and length are frame-dependent concepts and, even if it seems counterintuitive, this applies also to the concept of simultaneity. Take a look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity